# JavaScript scroll with static background and animating text and/or image

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, scroll

I'm looking for either a plug-in or pure JS/Jquery solution for a scrolling animation.

Basically when users scrolls to a certain section, and continues scrolling, the background of that section stays still while text and images fade in and out (on top of that static background) as user scrolls.

It's similar to this website: http://www.bagigia.com/ scroll down to "designer" "the idea", you'll get a good idea of what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: Did you try [ScrollMagic](http://scrollmagic.io/)?

Comment: I did see that but viewing their example page http://scrollmagic.io/examples/index.html I didn't see any that fits my needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with just css

```
body {
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```